# What is the best way to get a method name in runtime?

Tags: java, performance, logging

Here is a little background of my problem: I implemented a singleton logger class which is being called from several projects.

I want to log the name of the class as well as the name of the method asked for logging.

So far, I thought about two ways to get the name of the method and the class - either by reflection or by manually writing them.

The advantage of using reflection is that whenever the name of the class or the method will be renamed, which is not that often, it will be updated automatically.

The disadvantage of reflection is that it is performance consuming and it is suggested not to use it whenever you can avoid it, as can be seen in the documentation of reflection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or in various threads online.

What would be the best way and why?

Comment: Ummm...how could this question be language agnostic?

Comment: I thought it is language agnostic because reflection exist in a lot of languages, such as c#, java, python, etc. and logging as well.

Comment: in C/C++, just use `__func__` macro. no need to use reflection (and not possible to use reflection)

Comment: In C# you can use the CallerMemberName attribute to get the name of the method that is calling your method, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx.

Comment: You can call `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` and iterate down the call stack.  I think the current method on the stack would be position 0, so `new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1]` would probably do what you need.  Beware the performance costs of creating a `Throwable`.  Don't let logging slow down your application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume we're talking about Java by the link.  You're right of course.  The tradeoff is speed vs development time / hassle.

A popular logging library called [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) takes a classname or string as a initialization parameter.  Successive logging performed by the class will automatically offer the class name as possible information to output into the log without having to specify it at every line.  I don't find it to be that much of a hassle done like this.  In fact, in eclipse if you check under Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates, you can predefine new classes to automatically instantiate a logger passing the class name as a parameter to save you time, at least for what concerns the class name.

Alternatively, you can use [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) as a means to get a handle of a method prior to a call to a logger so that you can add the class name as well.  AspectJ can work in runtime as well as at compile time, and in the latter case, you will not see the performance drop that you would see using reflection since it modifies the code prior to compilation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried to remain language agnostic, because I am looking for the best approach disregarding a specific language - same performance drop appears in C# and other languages.

So just to make sure, you recommend to declare the names manually and in addition you suggested ways to cut the time / hassle waste a bit?

Comment: @OzRadiano Pretty much.  Most languages offer a way to modify the code in predictable ways prior or during compilation so that it is no longer reflection (aka runtime checking).  Lacking that, it is really up to you about what is more important.  If I had to pick, I'd prefer having to manually specify the method.

Comment: Thanks. In my code I declare the name of the classes as consts and use it for the logging.